# Generating a new variable if any of the conditions are met without list all variables in R

Tags: r

I would like to generate a variable called **outcome** which assigns 1 if any of the columns in the dataset below have any form of consent response else assign 0. However, I do not want to list all variables in my code.
I have tried the following code;

```
vars<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4")
dat<-dat%>% 
  mutate(outcome = case_when(if_any(vars, ~ .x == "consented now"|
                                            "consented later") ~ 1))
```

**dataset**

```
dat1 <- tibble(
  a1 = c("consented now", NA, NA, NA),
  a2= c("", "Refused", NA, NA),
  a3= c(NA, "consented now", NA, NA),
  a4= c(NA, NA, NA, "consented later"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `case_when`, with `if_any` and `grepl`:

```r
dat1 %>% 
  mutate(outcome = +if_any(a1:a4, ~ grepl("consented", .x)))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 5
#  a1            a2        a3            a4              outcome
#  <chr>         <chr>     <chr>         <chr>             <int>
#1 consented now ""        NA            NA                    1
#2 NA            "Refused" consented now NA                    1
#3 NA             NA       NA            NA                    0
#4 NA             NA       NA            consented later       1
```

Answer (score 1):

A *base* variant using `paste` with `do.call` and `grepl` might be:

```
dat1$outcome <- +grepl("consented", do.call(paste, dat1))

dat1
#             a1      a2            a3              a4 outcome
#1 consented now                  <NA>            <NA>       1
#2          <NA> Refused consented now            <NA>       1
#3          <NA>    <NA>          <NA>            <NA>       0
#4          <NA>    <NA>          <NA> consented later       1
```

Or using `rowSums` and `sapply`.

```
dat1$outcome <- +(rowSums(sapply(dat1, grepl, pattern="consented")) > 0)
```